# clGetProgramInfo CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES Incorrect Results?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to cache a program in a file so that it does not need to compile to assembly.  Consequently, I am trying to dump the binaries.  I am getting an issue where the binary program returned alternately has garbage data at the end.

Error checking omitted for clarity (no errors occur, though):

```
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, 0,NULL, &n);
n /= sizeof(size_t);

size_t* sizes = new size_t[n];
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, n*sizeof(size_t),sizes, NULL);
```

I have confirmed that kernel->program is identical between times.  In the above code, "n" is invariably 1, but sizes[0] varies between 2296 and 2312 alternate runs.

The problem is that the 2296 number appears to be more accurate--after the final closing brace in the output, there are three newlines and then three spaces.

For the 2312 number, after the final closing brace in the output, there are the three newlines, a line of garbage data, and then the three spaces.

Naturally, the line of garbage data is problematic.  I'm not sure how to get rid of it, and I'm pretty sure it's not an error on my part.

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 580M, with driver 305.60 on Windows 7.

**Update:** I have changed the code to the following:

```
//Get how many devices there are
size_t n;
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, 0,NULL, &n);

//Get the list of binary sizes
size_t* sizes = new size_t[n];
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, n*sizeof(size_t),sizes, NULL);

//Get the binaries
unsigned char** binaries = new unsigned char*[n];
for (int i=0;i<(int)n;++i) {
    binaries[i] = new unsigned char[sizes[i]];
}
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES, n*sizeof(unsigned char*),binaries, NULL);
```

Now, the code has n = 4, but only sizes[0] contains meaningful information (so the alloc of sizes[1] fails in the loop).  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, 0,NULL, &n);
```

needs to be:

```
clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, sizeof(size_t), &n, NULL);
```

Comment: I . . . don't know why I had it that way.  But this fixes it.  denis2342 got it first, but you explain better.  +1 to him, accept for you.

Answer (score 1):

I get the number of devices with the following line:

clGetProgramInfo(kernel->program, CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES, sizeof(cl_uint), &n, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

clGetProgramInfo with CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES and CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES needs a pointer to an array and not just to a single variable because it creates binaries for each device that you supplied when building the program. That is why the first line returns nothing. n for the second example should be the number of devices.

Not sure why the second example is different for each run... are you sure you are building for the same device each time?

Comment: The first line is intended to return the size of the array.  I cannot possibly pass an array, because I don't know the size.  Once I have the size (1) stored into n, then I can allocate the array and call the line again.  I'm pretty sure it's the same device--at least I'm not changing it myself.

Comment: My point is that n is supposed to be the number of devices in the context. And if you want to get number of devices associated with the program you have to use CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES and not CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES in the first line. See http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramInfo.html

Comment: Bleh, it appears I left out the line "n /= sizeof(size_t);" line (I think it was that) in my original code--so I think what my code did was the same thing.  I have made the changes suggested.  Please see update.

Comment: You only have one GPU connected to the system, right? So n shouldn't be 4, it should be 1. The return type of CL_PROGRAM_NUM_DEVICES is cl_uint and not size_t. Try changing the type of n to cl_uint, maybe that works.

Comment: There should be only one GPU: it's a laptop with, as before NVIDIA GeForce GTX 580M.  The function doesn't exist for cl_uint, but changing n to cl_uint and casting its address to size_t* so that it works still returns n == 4.